# PHP CURL to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

here's my code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost:2304/index.php/testproj/files/add/';

    $name = "test";
    $fields = array(
            'name'=>urlencode($name)
    );

    $fields_string = "";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);
//close connection
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I am trying to send post data to a CodeIgniter controller. I decided to use CURL to do the job. however, it doesn't work, when I put "blah" in my controller, it doesn't return anything. When I access the URL directly, it shows "blah".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use my [Curl library](http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl):

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$result = $this->curl->simple_get('http://example.com/');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thank you, you are my god. :) I am avid reader of your blog, I use ion_auth, I see your name pop up everywhere I go around using codeigniter. thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've been using CI a while so had a long time to write stuff. Hope the library works out for you :)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this into options

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

**Edit 1**

add this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// and post the result of $result
```